# Does "has been nothing short of amazing" mean it is a short time interval?

Tags: meaning

From this [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=M64sDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=While%20the%20use%20of%20deep%20learning%20by%20the%20medical%20image%20processing%20community%20trailed%20that%20of%20the%20computer%20vision%20community%20by%20a%20couple%20of%20years,%20the%20uptake%20of%20deep%20learning%20in%20medical%20research%20has%20been%20nothing%20short%20of%20amazing&source=bl&ots=gNQLAzO68l&sig=ACfU3U05dMS-xLphtWh8THa-qtOpl-y0Iw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfqITfoLvjAhWEAp0JHdDACYAQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=While%20the%20use%20of%20deep%20learning%20by%20the%20medical%20image%20processing%20community%20trailed%20that%20of%20the%20computer%20vision%20community%20by%20a%20couple%20of%20years%2C%20the%20uptake%20of%20deep%20learning%20in%20medical%20research%20has%20been%20nothing%20short%20of%20amazing&f=false) "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> While the use of deep learning by the medical image processing
>   community trailed that of the computer vision community by a couple of
>   years, the uptake of deep learning in medical research has been
>   nothing short of amazing.

I googled this and found a lot of "Today has been nothing short of amazing"

Does "has been nothing short of amazing" mean it is a short time interval?

Answer (score 1):

*Short of...* means lacking something. *He's short of some grades to get admission in the college.* Here, it means he lacks some grades. He's not qualified.

*Nothing short of...* means not lacking something. To simplify, *nothing short of...* means [*almost the same as...*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nothing--short--of)

So, here, *nothing short of amazing* means *indeed, it's amazing!*

Comment: Thank you very much! so, the original content means `although the use of deep learning by the medical image processing community trailed that of the computer vision community by a couple of years`, **the breakthrough in medical research brought by deep learning is markedly huge**. Is my understanding right?